# C# send SMS with HTTP Header, SMIL and MIME-Multipart

Tags: c#, sms, httprequest, mime, smil

Hello everyone I am currently working on a SMS project using Post Method of C#. However there are some SMIL and MIME multipart which I had to implement by C#. How should I insert them into my code? I have done something for the HTTP header already.

Here is my request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="myboundary"
From: 12345678
To: 12345678
Password: my_Password
Username: my_UserName

--myboundary
Content-Type: application/smil
Content-ID: <abc.smil>
Content-Location: abc.smil

//some <smil> here...
```

Here are my code so far:

```
        string username = "myusername";
        string password = "mypassword";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary = my boundary";
        string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are calling some API to send SMS. Did you try adding SMIL header instead of boundary header? Do you understand why API call needs SMIL header to be sent instead of boundary header? What API are you calling to send SMS?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I didn't add it, all I know about SMIL is just something like HTML, where they are different according to different formats like text, image. Is it SMIL can do more work then boundary header? As it can include more content. I'm still choosing a suitable API, I'm still reading articles about similar systems...

Comment: I have no idea about what SMIL is. You need to check the API documentation to understand why it is needed and how it is better.